# Database reset to the initial version

Tags: python, json, database, heroku, telegram-bot

I have a python bot on a free account. he has a database in json. records should be added. but sometimes reset to the initial version. How can this be avoided?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.   It's difficult to know what the problem actually is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.